# How to use PHPUnit Skeleton Generator on classless php files?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, automated-tests, code-generation

I heard about PHPUnit's ability to automatically generate base test files from this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-phpunit-testing-annotations-and-mocking/

(Note that PHPUnit-skelgen is now a sepparate utility from the rest of the PHPUnit project, it's source can be found here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator)

If I use phpunit-skelgen on the following piece of code:

```
<?php

class TestClass {

    /**
     * @assert (1, 2) == 3
     */
    function add($a, $b) {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
?>
```

By running `phpunit-skelgen generate-test TestClass`, I am greeted with the following test method (along with the usual phpunit boilerplate):

```
/**
 * Generated from @assert (1, 2) == 3.
 *
 * @covers TestClass::add
 */
public function testAdd()
{
    $this->assertEquals(
        3,
        $this->object->add(1, 2)
    );
}
```

My question is, is it possible to have phpunit-skelgen create tests for a php file without classes in it? For example, I have a rather large file with several global action functions I would like to have phpunit-skelgen create tests for, but I do not see a way to do so without wrapping my existing code in a class.

---

Edit: This is the output if I try to run phpunit-skelgen on a php file with functions but no class:

```
theguy@workpc ~/Projects/PHPUnitSamples $ phpunit-skelgen generate-test noClass
phpunit-skelgen 2.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.




[RuntimeException]                                                                    
Could not find class "noClass" in "/home/perry/Projects/PHPUnitSamples/noClass.php".  



generate-test [--bootstrap="..."] class [class-source] [test-class] [test-source]
```

---

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Also, I noticed that recent documentation for phpunit-skelgen is extremely scarce. Does anyone know of some good tutorials or manuals or something that have been written since phpunit-skelgen was moved into it's own separate project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation might be scarce but the first line is quite clear about the purpose:

> phpunit-skelgen is a tool that can generate skeleton test classes from production code **classes** and vice versa.

(highlight added)

So the answer is, it's not possible.